# How do I find out in which of the shapes I'm clicking using LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

notes: these shapes are PNGs with transparency.
How do I find out in which of the shapes I'm clicking ?

[image]

```
class Component extends Actor {

    private Pixmap pixmap;
    private Texture texture;

    public Component(String name, FileHandle file) {
        this.pixmap = new Pixmap(file);
        this.texture = new Texture(pixmap);
        setName(name);
        setBounds(0, 0, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY());
    }

    public Pixmap getPixmap() {
        return pixmap;
    }       
}
```

**
public class Shapes extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor ... 
**

```
public void create() {
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    Group group = new Group();

    Component cpn01 = new Component("01", Gdx.files.internal("01.png"));
    Component cpn02 = new Component("02", Gdx.files.internal("02.png"));
    Component cpn03 = new Component("03", Gdx.files.internal("03.png"));

    cpnBlue.setPosition(100f, 50f);
    cpnRed.setPosition(150f, 70f);
    cpnGreen.setPosition(175f, 100f);

    group.addActor(cpn01);
    group.addActor(cpn02);
    group.addActor(cpn03);

    stage.addActor(group);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    Group group = (Group) stage.getActors().first();

    for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildren().size; i++) {
        Component c = (Component) group.getChildren().get(i);

        Vector2 vc = c.screenToLocalCoordinates(new Vector2((float) screenX, (float) screenY));
        Pixmap pix = c.getPixmap();

        int pixel = pix.getPixel((int) vc.x, (int) vc.y);
        int transparency = ((pixel & 0xff000000) >> 24);

        if ((pixel & 0x000000ff) != 0) {
            Gdx.app.log("HIT", c.getName() + ", " + pixel + ", " + transparency);
            break;
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

**I would like to select only the shapes, ignoring the transparent pixels of the PNG.**

Comment: [ If the shape is in gradient? How can I find out object Actor corresponding to image (PNG) ]

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. You need to show your code for how you're loading/storing/drawing these, because there are probably dozens of different ways you could be doing it which is completely relevant to the answer. And what method are you using to determine "clicking"? And please explain what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getPixel method of your Pixmap with your mouse-position.

```
int val = pixmap.getPixel(x, y);
```

Then you can extract the RGBA values from the result

```
Color.rgba8888ToColor(color, val);
int R = (int)(color.r * 255f);
int G = (int)(color.g * 255f);
int B = (int)(color.b * 255f);
int A = (int)(color.a * 255f);
```

If the alpha value is greater 0 you could check which of the colors is clicked.

Comment: If the shape is in gradient? How can I find out object Actor corresponding to image (PNG)